# SFML C++ Строительство

Tags: c++, sfml

решил сделать небольшую игру и я хочу сделать в ней строительство. Я использую тайл карту и я бы хотел узнать каким образом я могу осуществить строительство? Причем, оно должно выравниваться по тайлам (как по некой сетке). И как мне для этого нарисовать какое-то здание? Оно должно состоять из нескольких тайлов или можно нарисовать сплошное здание (одной картинкой)?

https://github.com/Cominta/pixeled-civil

На всякий, оставлю репозиторий со всем кодом

Comment: К примеру как вы себе представляете абстракцию  Engine has  a components:  
       { sf::RenderWindow*  ,         sf::Event ,       std::stack<State*> ,         std::map<std::string, int>,          bool ,       int,      sf::Clock ,       float ,         std::map<std::string, sf::Texture*>  ... } ?   Я бы пересмотрел весь дизайн и подход...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас есть функция `TileMap::render`, которая, как я понимаю, рисует тайлы на карте. Код, который "рисует" что то на карте, должен просто поменять содержимое нужных тайлов (в Вашем случае - текстуру - `...->sprite->setTexture(*this->texture);`) и код отрисовки автоматически все отрисует.

То есть, "строительство" это просто изменение состояния тайла (или его спрайта). А код отрисовки уже сразу все отрисует.

Если здание занимает один тайл (одну клеточку), то тут все просто, если же тайл занимает несколько клеточек, то нужно просто подготовить несколько отдельных спрайтов с кусочками здания и правильно разместить. Да, тут возникает вопрос, а что делать, если два здания находятся рядом и "накладываются". Тут есть два варинта - либо просто отрисовывать поверх (то есть просто для одного здания будет использоваться только часть тайлов) либо просто не давать постоить так здания (очень популярная технология).

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло понять

Comment: думаю, что этот туториал https://github.com/EmilyMansfield/citybuilder может сильно помочь